# Compare row values in an array and remove those having nearly identical values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array:

```
a= [[2,3,50], [5,6,5], [8,10,5], [1,3,51] , [8,10,12]]
```

I would like to compare rows and remove those having nearly identical values.
For instance [2,3,50] and [1,3,51] are almost identical (the difference in each  value is less than 1).

At the end, I should get the following array:

```
a= [[2,3,50], [5,6,5], [8,10,5], [8,10,12]]
```

where [1,3,51] has been removed. 
Is there an efficient to do this in Python, avoiding multiple loops ?
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can perform outer subtraction, outer on the first axes of two versions of `a` and then get the absolute value and check if all values along the common axis is lesser than or equal to the threshold value of `1`. This will give us a `2D` mask. We need to select the upper triangular mask to make sure the closeby pairs are not accounted for more than once. Reset the diagonal ones that correspong to own cases. Finally, check if there's at least match in each col, which are the closeby ones that we need to remove. Hence, invert the mask and select rows off `a`.

The implementation would be -

```
a[~np.triu((np.abs(a[:,None,:]-a)<=1).all(2),1).any(0)]
```

Sample run with step-by-step execution should help clarify.

Input array :

```
In [112]: a
Out[112]: 
array([[ 2,  3, 50],
       [ 5,  6,  5],
       [ 8, 10,  5],
       [ 1,  3, 51],
       [ 8, 10, 12]])
```

Steps :

```
In [114]: (np.abs(a[:,None,:]-a)<=1).all(2)
Out[114]: 
array([[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]])

In [115]: np.triu((np.abs(a[:,None,:]-a)<=1).all(2),1)
Out[115]: 
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])

In [116]: np.triu((np.abs(a[:,None,:]-a)<=1).all(2),1).any(0)
Out[116]: array([False, False, False,  True, False])

In [117]: ~np.triu((np.abs(a[:,None,:]-a)<=1).all(2),1).any(0)
Out[117]: array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True])

In [118]: a[~np.triu((np.abs(a[:,None,:]-a)<=1).all(2),1).any(0)]
Out[118]: 
array([[ 2,  3, 50],
       [ 5,  6,  5],
       [ 8, 10,  5],
       [ 8, 10, 12]])
```

Just to do one more round of verification, let's set the last row as another closeby of the second-last row. This should lead to the last row being removed too. Hence -

```
In [120]: a[-1] = [0,3,52]

In [122]: a
Out[122]: 
array([[ 2,  3, 50],
       [ 5,  6,  5],
       [ 8, 10,  5],
       [ 1,  3, 51],
       [ 0,  3, 52]])

In [123]: a[~np.triu((np.abs(a[:,None,:]-a)<=1).all(2),1).any(0)]
Out[123]: 
array([[ 2,  3, 50],
       [ 5,  6,  5],
       [ 8, 10,  5]])
```

**With one-loop for memory-efficiency**

We can use one loop to save on memory and hence being efficient on that front and also make use of slicing in the process -

```
n = len(a)
mask = np.zeros(n, dtype=bool)
for i in range(n-1):
    mask[i+1:] |= (np.abs(a[i+1:]-a[i])<=1).all(1)
out = a[~mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

A few questions about the definition of the problem.

First:  Suppose we have an array `[ ... a1 ... a2 ... ]`, where `a1` and `a2` are "nearly identical"; which one do we remove?  This is pretty easy to resolve:  pick the first one.

Second:  Suppose we have an array `[ b1 ... bN ]` where `bi` and  `bi+1` are nearly identical but `bi` and `bi+2` are *not* nearly identical.  Which ones do we remove?  In this case, I guess you could remove all the odd entries or all the even entries.

Third:  what about a midway situation where you have a mix-and-match of nearly identical successive pairs?  What's the prescription?

I think the problem is related to the fact that "nearly identical" is not transitive, unlike "strictly identical".  This suggests the following approach, which defines a somewhat different criterion for "nearly identical":  Define a hash function that maps rows into "OK rows"; for example, round all elements of the rows down to an even number.  Then define "nearly identical" to be all rows that map into the same "OK row".  You could define a map from "OK row" to list of nearly identical rows in `a`, and return the first element of each list.

Perhaps it would help to have a little more context for the question.  For example, I'm working on a problem involving a large number of time series's.  I'd like to predict the next value in each of the series's, using SARIMA.  However, the cost of building one SARIMA model for each series is prohibitive, so what I do (in brief) is cluster the series's using K-Means clustering with a value of K such that building K SARIMA models is acceptable.  In this case, what I'm *hoping* is that different series's in the same cluster are "nearly identical enough" that one prediction serves for both.

Comment: Sure. What I am doing is to detect "lines" (these are actually filaments in an image). For that, I am using a Hough transform. The result gives me lines. Sometimes, the algorithm gives two lines, which are very close to each other (almot same start position, almost same length and almsot same slope). I wanted to remove those duplicates.